# Account name not populating when Email2Case is used

Tags: email2case

When users choose to create a case from an email it does not auto populate the *Account* name in the *Case* form. It works fine if you view a customer and create a case from the detail view page but not from an email (the customer does exist with the same email address.)

Also when I view a customers details it's not showing the emails in the history, so it's obviously not linking the email with the account.

**Update**

Here is a code sample:

```
List<String> subjectParts = email.subject.split('_') Select account where name = subjectParts.get(0); List<String> servers = subjectParts.get(1).split('-'); 
Select a.Id, (Select Id, Subject From Cases where IsClosed = false AND Subject = :servers.get(0)) From Account a Create case. case.Subject = servers.get(0);
```

Comment: Please be clear.Can you explain in more depth your problem scenario?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to apex? Are you using standard email to case or is this a custom functionality?

Comment: please add code samples. If you have your email2case installed on what server? is that server communicating correctly with your app?

Comment: yeah every thing is working properly but account fiels is not populating  List<String> subjectParts = email.subject.split('_') Select account where name = subjectParts.get(0); List<String> servers = subjectParts.get(1).split('-'); Select a.Id, (Select Id, Subject From Cases where IsClosed = false AND Subject = :servers.get(0)) From Account a Create case. case.Subject = servers.get(0); –

Comment: Are you using the native Email2Case functionality or parsing emails with custom code?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few reasons why the Contact is not being attached:

1. The email did not match any Contacts
2. The email matched more than one Contact
3. The email is not in the standard email field (Salesforce will not match on custom fields.)

**Edit**

The Account field is generally populated based on the Case's Contact; when the Contact is populated Salesforce automatically pulls in the Contact's Account. If you aren't setting the Contact lookup I suspect that is why the Account is blank.

Comment: When users choose to create a case from an email it does not auto populate the account name in the case form. It works fine if you view a customer and create a case from the detailview page but not from an email (Yes the customer does exist with the same email address)

Also when I view a customers details it's not showing the emails in the history, so it's obviously not linking the email with the account.

Comment: Cases to be automatically created In salesforce.com based on emails sent . These Cases will be associated with the relevant Account In salesforce.com based on the contact details of the original sender of the Email. Creating the code to parse the Email to extract Account record and create Case including child Cases. In this format
 
AccountName_ServerInstant-AlartName
 
this format is the subject of Email subject is from subject field from case object, and Email body is description field In case object. If subsequent emails are sent before the Case is manually closed  t

Comment: Is the Contact populated but not the Account or are both blank? Email2Case doesn't work with Accounts.

Comment: both fields blank

Comment: Your customers are in the system as Contacts, right?

Comment: yes, if the customer is not existing than account need to be created with the contact

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is more than one contact using the same email addresss. Therefore, the account/contact are not automatically populated.

In regards to the second issue, are you sure you have added the "email" related list to the page layout.?

Comment: List<String> subjectParts = email.subject.split('_')
 Select account where name = subjectParts.get(0);
 List<String> servers = subjectParts.get(1).split('-');
 
Select a.Id, (Select Id, Subject From Cases where IsClosed = false AND Subject = :servers.get(0)) From Account a
 Create case.
 case.Subject = servers.get(0);

Comment: need to sort out by above way